# Rails isn't recognizing Rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I was working on a project just fine, logged off for the night and the next morning when I tried to start again I was getting this error:

```
Missing the Rails 2.3.12 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.12 rails`,
update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb
for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION
to use the latest version installed.
```

I did a `gem list` and it's definitely installed:

```
rails (3.1.0, 2.3.14, 2.3.12, 2.3.8)
```

I also made sure that `2.3.12` was the required Gem in the `environment.rb`:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.12' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

Before I logged off I deployed my changes to demo, which was working fine, and when I checked it the next morning I was getting the same error message.

I'm still pretty new to RoR so I am not sure how to trouble shoot this.

Comment: Well -- it's not random. Something in your environment has definitely changed.

Comment: how are you using gems ? Freezed or unfreezed ?

Comment: did u see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684797/missing-rails-gem ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before and it was because I was defaulting to the system version of ruby. Run "ruby -v" in console and make sure you are using the version you want to. If you are not run this in the console:

```
$ rvm use "x"
```

Where "x" is the version of ruby you want to use.

Also, make sure your gemsets are in order. You can create and start using a new gemset by running this in the console ("xxx" = what you want to call your gemset):

```
$ rvm gemset create xxx
$ rvm gemset use xxx
```

After creating (and switching to) the gemset you can try reinstalling rails. Creating a new gemset means that there are no gems associated with whatever project you are working on anymore. So you will need to reinstall all your other gems too. Should be easy with a "bundle install"

Hope this helps.